# Retrofit common header without OkHttp?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

#### Problem:

Today I faced an exception in OkHttp.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 19

I get to know that Okhttp is not supporting <21 versions devices anymore.

From [github page of Okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) & also on [github issues](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4622), from okhttp version 3.13 -

> OkHttp works on Android 5.0+ (API level 21+) and on Java 8+.

It is a very major change because all my projects are running on `minSdkVersion = 16`. Or at least 19.

#### What I tried?

- There is an way to add header in each request individually as documented in [Retrofit official page](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), but this will need to add header manually in each request.
- I don't want to use old version of Okhttp. Because it may lead me for unexpected issues that are being fixed in newer okhttp versions. (or should I use old one?)

#### What I need:

**I don't want remove support for ~10% devices** (if I increase `minSdkVersion` to 21+) only for using Okhttp. I use Okhttp for adding a common header to all request of Retrofit.

Is there a way to add common header without use of Okhttp?

Comment: Retrofit uses okhttp under the hood, so I think the best way is moving to earlier version of retrofit and okhttp client.

Comment: what's wrong with using an Interceptor for that?

Comment: @Blackbelt are you referring to Okhttp interceptor?.

Comment: yes, I guess I am

Comment: @Ufkoku I am in search for another possible solutions. Because moving to earlier version would be a temporary solution.

Comment: @Blackbelt sir, Okhttp removed support for <21 versions devices in latest versions. and I am not willing to stop 10% of devices support just for adding a header. So I am searching an alternate.

Comment: what version of okhttp/retrofit are you using ?

Comment: use  `OkHttp 3.12.2`

Comment: @Blackbelt sir, upgraded to `3.13.1`.

Comment: Look into Volley; https://github.com/google/volley It is supported by Google. The only con to it is that it is not well documented and you'd have to do more work in order to set it up to work exactly like Retrofit. More here; https://developer.android.com/training/volley Otherwise, you'd have to go the way you're going with adding the headers to retrofit requests yourself.

Comment: I mean, nobody is forcing you in using latest version. Just use an old version of both

Comment: @Blackbelt yes, that's a final solution. Let's see, if there's an alternate also. Is there not any other interceptor class available else Okhttp?

Comment: you can manually add `@Header` on every call defined in your `Service`

Comment: @Blackbelt sir, thanks for help, I am aware of that.

Comment: Use 3.12.2. https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5-818bb78d07ce

Answer (score 0):

You use Interceptor to add all headers you want like this :

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            Request request;

            @Override
            public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {

                request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + GlobalClass.accessToken)
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json").build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        }).addNetworkInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
```

and return builder with this

```
 return builder.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

Comment: Note im using this for API 19+

Comment: Which version of Okhttp you are using.

Comment: com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5

Comment: com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0

Comment: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0

Comment: i am facing the same problem ... and could not find the solution for that.... my clients use api-19...